# Bad image error Blender 2.9 (Asking again because the previous info was wrong)

Tags: error

Yesterday I asked a question about a dll file error, but the error description I pasted was wrong. Hence asking again with correct error code

Today Blender 2.9 crashed on a normal scene and it never booting up again. It shows "Bad image "error with DL2.dll I have tried everything from changing the Dll file to re installing the software, Even USB bootable version is not working.

Any thoughts ?

Here is the error

> `C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\blender2.9\SD2.dll is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error. Try installing the program again using the original installation media or contact your system administrator or the software vendor for support. Error status 0xc000022”`

Comment: Could be be perhaps trying to run the program on the wrong architecture? Download the 'portable' version from the 'other versions' drop-down at https://www.blender.org/download/ - but ensure you're using the right one for your system (eg, must have 64-bit Windows for running the 64-bit version).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem was that Simple Direct media Layer (SDL) is considered as a game engine and blocked my employers firewall.
This may not be an issue in personal computers, but something to watch out for in work and school systems.

Thanks for the help